# Is a black hole the opposite of a cosmic gusher?

Tags: black-holes, white-holes

If a black hole sucks things into it and a white hole ejects things, then do objects absorbed by black holes exit from a white hole?

Answer (score 1):

The evidence for white holes is flaky at best, but if the answer to your question were to be yes, it would require a wormhole between blackholes and whiteholes

Also worth noting: even in theory, a whitehole cannot be sustained for a measurable period of time as the matter would either create some sort of massive object or it ejects the matter at high speeds